# mysql query. How to make other results to be null?

Tags: mysql

```
-- print out stores at the same regions and their addresses
SELECT A.address AS LE, B.address AS LC,  C.address AS LW, D.address AS LS, E.address AS LN FROM
(SELECT region, address FROM postcode WHERE region = 'LE') A,
(SELECT region, address FROM postcode WHERE region = 'LC') B,
(SELECT region, address FROM postcode WHERE region = 'LW') C,
(SELECT region, address FROM postcode WHERE region = 'LS') D,
(SELECT region, address FROM postcode WHERE region = 'LN') E;
```

I want to make a table with LE, LC, LW, LS and LN separately from one table 'postcode'. I have coded up till here, but the problem is that the addresses are duplicated. There are different numbers of addresses in each region, and it is not erased by DISTINCT. I know that my code is wrong so, could you give me some suggestions for modification?

| StoreName | Address |
| --- | --- |
| Mall of America | 2312L, the South, Lukewarm |
| The Shops at Columbus Circle | 43824, the East, Lukewarm |
| Sawgrass Mills | 44138, the Center, Lukewarm |
| The Galleria | 78AB, the North, Lukewarm |
| The Grove | 81531, the Center, Lukewarm |
| King of Prussia Mall | 81HE3, the West, Lukewarm |

This is the sample data

| LE | LC | LW | LS | LN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 43824, the East, Lukewarm | 44138, the Center, Lukewarm | 81HE3, the West, Lukewarm | 2312L, the South, Lukewarm | 78AB, the North, Lukewarm |
|  | 81531, the Center, Lukewarm |  |  |  |

Comment: You're just making a cartesian product of all the subquery results.

Comment: Can you show some sample data and the desired result?

Comment: This kind of data manipulation is better done in the client.

Comment: Agree. Handle issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of data manipulation is better done in the client.  But you could do:

```
select le.address, lc.address, lw.address, ls.address, ln.address
from (select row_number() over () rn from postcode where region=(select region from postcode group by region order by count(*) desc limit 1)) maxrows
left join (select address, row_number() over () rn from postcode where region='LE') le using (rn)
left join (select address, row_number() over () rn from postcode where region='LC') lc using (rn)
left join (select address, row_number() over () rn from postcode where region='LW') lw using (rn)
left join (select address, row_number() over () rn from postcode where region='LS') ls using (rn)
left join (select address, row_number() over () rn from postcode where region='LN') ln using (rn)
```